# What method reduce understand as acumulator in this particular script

Tags: javascript, reduce

I can´t understand in this particular script how reduce works. I though that reduce always treats first argument as a acumulator, but in this ocassion the var result = [] seems to be the acumulator or maybe I am wrong. Initially I understood that fist argument of function symDiff (arrayOne) should be the accumulator for reduce method.

```
  function sym() {
  var args = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    args.push(arguments[i]);
  }


    function symDiff(arrayOne, arrayTwo) {
    var result = [];

    arrayOne.forEach(function(item) {
      if (arrayTwo.indexOf(item) < 0 && result.indexOf(item) < 0) {
        result.push(item);
      }
    });

    arrayTwo.forEach(function(item) {
      if (arrayOne.indexOf(item) < 0 && result.indexOf(item) < 0) {
        result.push(item);
      }
    });

      return result;
    }

// Apply reduce method to args array, using the symDiff function
return args.reduce(symDiff);
}


sym([1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1, 4]);
```

Comment: in every next phase, the accumulator is the value returned from the previous one, so yes, if you return `result` array, in the second phase the accumulator will be `result` array that you returned in previous

Comment: Ok, it makes sense, but then, the reduce methos seems to be two current value arguments (arrayOne and arrayTwo). Is that possible?

Comment: From MDN:
You can provide initial value to the accumulator.
 If no initialValue is supplied, the first element in the array will be used as the initial accumulator value and skipped as currentValue.

Comment: …and it is in general a very bad idea to omit the initial value.

Comment: Ok, I understand that, but here accumulator seems to be the var = result, and (arrayOne and arrayTwo) arguments seems to be the currentValue argument. Is it possible both arguments (arrayOne and arrayTwo)  being the currentValue at the same time?